# AVR Timer not operating as quickly when changing number of PINs being turned on/off

Tags: avr, timer

I am following the [tutorial on AVR freaks on Timers written by @Dean Camera](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=50106). His code says:

```
#include <avr/io.h> 

int main (void) 
{ 
   DDRB |= (1 << 0); // Set LED as output 

   // TODO: Set up timer at Fcpu/64 

   for (;;) 
   { 
      // Check timer value in if statement, true when count matches 1 second 
      if (TCNT1 >= 15624) 
      { 
         PORTB ^= (1 << 0); // Toggle the LED 

         TCNT1 = 0; // Reset timer value 
      } 
   } 
}
```

This flashes one LED. I edited the code to turn on and off all pins on PORTB but my code "runs slower", with the LEDs appearing less bright. My code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(){
    DDRB= 0xFF;

    TCCR1B |= (1<<CS10) | (1 << CS11);

    PORTB = 0xFF;
for (;;) {
    if(TCNT1 >= 15624){
        PORTB = 0x00;
        TCNT1 = 0;
    } else {
        PORTB = 0xFF;
    }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? Also is there a better way to turn on/off the pins this is the only way I could think of. I am just running this on a STK500 with a mega 16L.

Comment: Might be worth using his name so he gets an alert @Dean Camera

Comment: Didn't think it would work in questions, but will try.

Comment: Can you describe how you're hooking up these LED's and which avr chip you are using?

Comment: @Jon I don't know, this is because I am using the STK500 development board so just have to plug a jumper wire across to the LEDs. I'm using a mega16L. Also would it make a difference as with the original code it operates as it should it "slows down" with the same set up just using all the pins running my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by your code you're doing the following:

Set up timer.

Start loop:
   Is timer at (or more than) one second?
       Yes:
           Turn off LEDs,
           Reset Timer
       No:
           Turn on LEDs.
Repeat loop.

This means that the LEDs are on for the entire timer count, then they turn off at 1 second.  They then immediately turn on again because the timer is no longer >= 1 second.

In the original example `PORTB ^= (1 << 0); // Toggle the LED` switches the LED on if it is off, or off if it is on.  What you should be doing is something like:

```
for (;;) {
    if(TCNT1 >= 15624){
        PORTB = ~PORTB;
        TCNT1 = 0;
    }
}
```

(I haven't tested this code, but the theory is sound)

Every second that passes the timer is reset and the LEDs are inverted.  You could pre-load PORTB with a value, and any LEDs that are off will be turned on, and any that are on will be turned off.

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry im tired and trying to relax after a hards day of maths revision. And trying to edit the code has ended with a BSOD on windows 7 :/.

Comment: @Dean Dontcha just love Windows?  That's why I work almost exclusively in Linux these days ;)

Comment: Thats done the trick. And no I love linux but i can't be bothered to configure an IDE for AVR development when there is a standard system on windows that is supported by atmel so I just use that.

Comment: Makefiles and Emacs.  All the IDE you'll ever need. ;-)

Comment: Emacs? Bleaugh!  Bloaty!  Vi forever!  (and that's VI, *not* VIM)